# Implement MSSQL's partition by windowed clause in Pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I’m in the process of moving a `MSSQL` database to `MYSQL` and have decided to move some stored procedures to `Python` rather than rewrite in `MYSQL`. I am using Pandas 0.23 on Python 3.5.4.

The old `MSSQL` base uses a number of windowed functions. So far I’ve had success with converting using Pandas using `pandas.Dataframe.rolling` as follows:

MSSQL

```
AVG([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY DateValue ROWS 13 PRECEDING) AS MA14
```

Python

```
df['MA14'] = df.Close.rolling(14).mean()
```

I'm stuck working on a solution for the **PARTITION BY** part of the MSSQL windowed function in python. I am working on a solution with `pandas groupby` based on feedback since posting...

```
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.0/groupby.html
```

For Example let's say MSSQL is:

```
AVG([Close]) OVER (PARTITION BY myCol ORDER BY DateValue ROWS 13 PRECEDING) AS MA14
```

**What I have worked out so far:**

`Col1` contains my categorical data which I wish to `groupby` and apply function to on a `rolling` basis. There is also a date column, thus `Col1` and the `date column` would represent a unique record in the `df`.

**1. Delivers the mean for Col1 albeit aggregated**

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Col1']).mean()
print(grouped.tail(20))
```

**2. Appears to be applying the rolling mean per categorical group of Col1. Which I am after**

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Col1']).Close.rolling(14).mean()
print(grouped.tail(20))
```

**3 Assign to df as new Column RM**

```
df['RM'] = df.groupby(['Col1']).Close.rolling(14).mean()
print(df.tail(20))
```

It doesn't like this step which I get the error...

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

**I've worked up a simple example which may help:**

How do I get the results of #2 in the df in #1 or similar.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dta = {'Colour': ['Red','Red','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Blue','Red','Blue','Blue','Blue','Red'],
         'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2018,2016,2017,2013,2013],
         'Val':[87,78,863,673,74,81,756,78,694,701,804,69]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dta)
df = df.sort_values(by=['Colour','Year'], ascending=True)
print(df)

#1 add calculated columns to the df. This averages all of column Val
df['ValMA3'] = df.Val.rolling(3).mean().round(0)
print (df)


#2 Group by Colour. This is calculating average by groups correctly. 
# where are the other columns from my original dataframe?
#what if I have multiple calculated columns to add? 

gf = df.groupby(['Colour'])
gf = gf.Val.rolling(3).mean().round(0)
print(gf)
```

Comment: Yes, I this is the correct approuch.  Using Groupby with rolling.

Comment: pandas `df.groupby` serves the function as the sql `group by` and also `window functions`, although it is not possible to _partition_ by multiple clauses in the same statement in pandas. yours is the right approach. what error messages are you getting?

Comment: good to confirm from you both I need to solve via groupby

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the window functions in MySQL? [This function executes as a window function if over_clause is present](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

Comment: Hi Alan - i am using mysql57. I believe windowed functions are not available until mysql8. For simple functions coding is of similar complexity SQL vs python, but for more complex calculations I'm finding python easier and more flexible than SQL implementation.

Comment: this is getting closer using transform...sorting is off though with the new grouped index aligning to the df index in the transform. `df['ValMA3'] = df.groupby(['Colour']).Val.rolling(3).mean().round(0).reset_index(name='ValMA3').transform('ValMA3')`

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure the transform function can help.

```
df.groupby('Col1'')['Val'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, 2).mean())
```

where e.g. the value 3 is the step of the rolling window, and 2 is the minimum number of periods.

(Just don't forget to sort your data frame before applying the running calculation)